# Error de inicializacion en variable string Java

Tags: java, string

[image]

Hola estaba haciendo un programa para saber el tipo de triangulo que es basado en sus coordenadas, el punto es que al declarar la variable string tip, me dice que no esta inicializada, por más que lineas mas adelante le de un valor segun se cumplan algunos requisitos, quisiera saber el por que no se inicializa, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @Raul, bienvenid@ a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que en Java, las variables locales no se incializan de forma implicita. Eso quiere decir que siempre hay que asignar una valor a una variable local en todos los casos.

En tu caso por ejemplo, tal y como tienes el código, existe una posiblidad en la que la variable `tip` no está tomando un valor que es cuando no se cumple la condición dentro del `if` ni se cumple la del `else if`, así que en ese caso la variable no tiene valor y el compilar da un error.

Tienes 2 opciones:

- O inicializas la variable al incio poniéndola a null `String tip = null;`
- O le das un valor dentro de un `else`

Comment: Por favor, si se vota negativo estaría saber por qué. Porque según mi criterio esta respuesta responde perfectamente a la pregunta

Comment: No he sido yo quien te ha votado negativo, pero la segunda opción que das no resolvería el problema. De hecho parece que sí que le está asignando un valor dentro del else, pero no de ve por el cuadro de error. y lo de iniciarla a null, no se si es buena idea... Tal vez sea mejor un String vacío.

Comment: Si pero yo me refiería a un `else` a secas, él lo tiene puesto en un `else if`. Lo que yo digo es que habría que inicializarlo para cualquier otra situación el `if`

Comment: Tienes razón, te marco la respuesta como útil para contrarrestar el negativo, jeje